# replacing string in multiple files

Tags: sed

I am piggybacking of an existing question - I'm not sure how to add this to that question. The examples I see replace a single string - I need to replace multiple strings.

I am trying to change the same string that exists in multiple files in a directory using 'sed'. The string has multiple words. The template I  using is:

```
sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt
```

I want to change in a number of files in the same directory - i.e. change the string:

```
&VARIABLE1 = 10000000
```

to

```
&VARIABLE = 1
```

When I use the following

```
sed -i 's/&VARIABLE1 = 10000000/&VARIABLE = 1/g' *.txt
```

It does not do the  substitution properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It was the ampersand that was giving me grief. When I removed it, it worked perfectly. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `&` character has a special meaning on the replacement side of a sed `s` command:

> ```
>           replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
>           portion  of  the  pattern  space  which matched, and the special
>           escapes \1 through \9 to refer  to  the  corresponding  matching
>           sub-expressions in the regexp.
> ```

To make it literal, you need to escape it, `\&`

Ex.

```
$ echo '&VARIABLE1 = 10000000' | sed 's/&VARIABLE1 = 10000000/&VARIABLE = 1/g'
&VARIABLE1 = 10000000VARIABLE = 1
```

but

```
$ echo '&VARIABLE1 = 10000000' | sed 's/&VARIABLE1 = 10000000/\&VARIABLE = 1/g'
&VARIABLE = 1
```